# Dryer timer switch motor

Tags: switch, dryer, timer, motor, bypass

Can I put a toggle switch in place of a dryer timer motor to turn the dryer on ?
I have tested for voltage coming into the dryer, it has voltage. I did all the standard tests on all the dryer components, Is it possible to put a switch temporarily in place of the timer switch motor to run the dryer ?

Comment: Thats a bit hard to answer. Model details and pictures would help

Answer (score 1):

I've never had one completely in bits to really check carefully, but the most basic ones have two* switches in the timer - one for the motor & one for the heater; so you can have that 10 minute cooldown phase at the end. We're going to need pictures to even guess at which circuit is which. You'll need a multi-meter to test open/close positions [with the power off].

Once you overcome that, then you'll have to tackle how the wires are attached. Usually they're on spade connectors, which you'll have to wreck to remove, unless they're also soldered, in which case you'd have to cut them short - meaning you might struggle to re-connect.

All in all, I'd wait until your new timer arrives.

*…and possibly a third, for the timer's own motor, though that may be shared with the dryer motor.